# input box not auto-adjusting to text bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug, inputbox

The input box width does not adjust to my placeholder text or the size of its content:

```
form.form-inline(role='form')
    div.form-group
        div.dropdown
            button.btn.btn-info.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown') {{loadButtonText}}
                span.caret
            ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
                li(ng-repeat='rss in RSSList')
                    a(href='#', ng-click="loadFeed(rss.url, $event);") {{rss.Title}}
        div.form-group
            input.form-control(type='text', autocomplete='off', placeholder="This is where your feed's url will appear" data-ng-model='url')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A plunker would be nice. Also as far as I know inputs in bootstrap are width 100% by default. They don't auto adjust based on value length.

Answer (score 0):

I cant paste the sample link but I found this for you.

```
<input placeholder="Please enter your name, address and shoe size">
<input placeholder="Please enter">

var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    input[i].setAttribute('size',input[i].getAttribute('placeholder').length);
}
```

because of paddings you may want to add 5-10px to length